# Read or Write from/to Parcel for an object which can not implement Parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a class like ObjectA which implements Parcelable.

```
public class ObjectA implements Parcelable {

       private ObjectB objB;
       private int mId;

}
```

ObjectB is coming from a .jar file added to project, and I can not implement Parcelable interface for that class.

```
private ObjectA(Parcel in) {

}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

}
```

So I wonder if there is any solution to read from Parcel or write to Parcel for ObjectB?

Of course `dest.writeParcelable` and `in.readParcelable` will not work since ObjectB can not implement Parcelable interface.

Comment: You can get properties from ObjectB via getters and write it to the Parcel and when you read from Parcel - you can create new ObjectB and set it by setters. If you don't have access and any setters/getter you can use reflection.

Comment: you can share your answer and I mark it as accepted @Konrad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get properties from `ObjectB` via getters and write it to the `Parcel` and when you read from `Parcel` - you can create new `ObjectB` and set it by setters. If you don't have access and any setters/getter you can use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible through using a handling object for ObjectB :

```
public class ObjectBHandler implements Parcelable {

private ObjectB b;


public ObjectBHandler(ObjectB b) {
    this.b = b;
}

public ObjectB getB() {
    return b;
}

public void setB(ObjectB b) {
    this.b = b;
}

/**
 * Describe the kinds of special objects contained in this Parcelable's
 * marshalled representation.
 *
 * @return a bitmask indicating the set of special object types marshalled
 * by the Parcelable.
 */
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Flatten this object in to a Parcel.
 *
 * @param dest  The Parcel in which the object should be written.
 * @param flags Additional flags about how the object should be written.
 *              May be 0 or {@link #PARCELABLE_WRITE_RETURN_VALUE}.
 */
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeDouble(b.getValue());
    //...
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you cannot implement the interface because it is in a jar, then there might be a solution :
If you know well enough the implementation of ObjectB and you know every field that should be recovered, and if ObjectB is not final, I guess you could still do something like this :

```
public class ParcelableObjectB extends ObjectB implements Parcelable {...}
```